# Number fields that are not separable over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I wonder whether there is a number field that is not separable over $\mathbb{Q}$. I look for it because in books, sometimes I see "separable" and sometimes do not. How can a minimal polynomial of an element has  multiple roots?

Comment: But $\Bbb Q$ is a [perfect field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_field).

Comment: It can only happen in characteristic $p$, for polynomials of the form $f(X^p)$.

Answer (score 2):

It can't happen for $\mathbb{Q}$ because that has characteristic zero.

In fact it can only happen for [infinite fields of finite characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_extension).